# Skip steps from remote azure pipeline template repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I want to use a remote repo template in my azure pipeline. But I want to skip some of the steps included.
Note: I dont have access to configure the repote pipeline steps.

The remote yml looks like this
*build.yml*

```
steps:
- download: none
- checkout: ${{ parameters.checkoutRepo }}

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Cache Maven local repo

- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven: validate'

- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
```

My yml *my-build.yml*

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my-remote-repo-above
      type: git
      name: my-remote-repo-above
    .
    .
    .
    stages:
  - template: build-stage.yml
    parameters:
```

So my question is, can I somehow specify steps from remote to skip OR there is a way to pick the ones I want to execute only?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we can define a [parameter to your template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters), and use it in a [task condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) so that we can skip the specific steps based on the condition.

For example, in *build-stage.yml*

```
parameters:
  enableSonarCloud: false

steps:
- download: none
- checkout: ${{ parameters.checkoutRepo }}

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Cache Maven local repo

- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven: validate'

- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ parameters.enableSonarCloud }} )
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
```

And your *build.yml*

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my-remote-repo-above
      type: git
      name: my-remote-repo-above
    .
    .
    .
    stages:
  - template: build-stage.yml
    parameters:
      enableSonarCloud: true
```

But in your scenario, you don't have access to configure the remote template steps. In this case, I don't think you can achieve that if the parameter and task condition is not defined in the template.